# Oracle select rows above and below condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select, conditional-statements

I'm selecting a certain value from an Oracle database. Once I select the value from the table is it possible to get the values directly above and below the one that I selected? If so, whats the best way to go about that? Have something like:

```
SELECT *
 FROM table_name
  WHERE name = 'F100'
```

So I would like to also select the values directly above and below 'F100' in the table

Data:

```
ID  | Name
123 | F300 <-
123 | F100 <-
123 | F700 <-
123 | F900
123 | F860
129 | F654
129 | F700 <-
129 | F100 <-
129 | F320 <-
129 | F790
```

Comment: :Can yopu show some data ,so that it will be very easy to understand what is requiored and expected

Comment: just added some let me know if that helps with understanding

Answer (score 3):

The rows in a table are inherently unordered.  Concepts like "first", "last", "next", and "previous" all require that you specify some way to sort the data.  Assuming that there is some numeric column, say, `id` that you want to order by and that you want the "next" or "previous" data based on that `id` and that you want the next and prior values whether or not they have a `name` of "F100"

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, 
               name, 
               lag(id) over (order by id) prior_id,
               lag(name) over (order by id) prior_name,
               lead(id) over (order by id) next_id,
               lead(id) over (order by id) next_name
          FROM your_table)
 WHERE name = 'F100'
```

Comment: so my data shows that the ID's are different but there are actually a large group of the same ID's (say 20 or 30) then a new ID starts with a repeat of 'Name' data. So would this still work if were sorting by ID even though a large group of them have the same ID?

Comment: @reddman - It's always helpful if you can post data that approximates the actual data you have.  If there are many rows with the same `id`, sorting just on `id` wouldn't guarantee that the "next" and "prior" rows would be the same every time.  You'd probably want to order by more than just the `id`-- perhaps you want to `order by id, name` if the combination of `id` an `name` is unique.  On the other hand, maybe you really want all the rows with the same `id` if there is one row with a `name` of "F100" which is a totally different requirement (and query).

Comment: hmm well when the data gets inserted into the table the order needs to remain the same for my situation when I query it. I guess I could create another column that counts the number of rows and just sort by that... Also changed my data example to model my situation more accurately

Comment: @reddman - If you want data sorted in the order in which it is inserted, you'd need to add either a date/ timestamp to the table or a sequence-generated column.  A column named `id` would generally imply that it was a key (and thus unique) so that seems like a poor choice for the name of a column that is going to have many repeating values.

Comment: for this situation each ID has numerous "names" and I need to be able to determine the ID the "name" corresponds to for further manipulation.

Comment: @reddman - Then `id` is a poor name for the attribute.  It isn't an identifier if it doesn't uniquely identify the row.

Comment: hahaha i seriously don't think you can judge what is a poor name for an attribute when you don't have any idea what my data pertains to